# Iterator for native Matrix class

Tags: c++

I wrote my own Matrix class with these fields:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    T *data = nullptr;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
```

Here is an iterator for this class, but it does not work correctly (for example, I can’t go over the entire array, assign values ​​to matrix elements, etc.). How can the iterator be modified so that it works correctly?

```
public:
    class Iterator
    {
        friend Matrix;

    private:
        T *curr;

    public:
        Iterator() : curr(nullptr) {}

        Iterator(Matrix *matrix) : curr(matrix->data) {}

        ~Iterator() = default;

        bool operator==(Iterator &it) const { return (curr == it.curr); }

        bool operator!=(Iterator &it) const { return (curr != it.curr); }

        Iterator &operator++()
        {
            ++(this->curr);
            return *this;
        }

        Iterator operator++(int)
        {
            Iterator temp = *this;
            this->operator++();
            return temp;
        }

        Iterator &operator+(int n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                ++(*this);
            }
            return *this;
        }

        T &operator*() { return curr->data; }

        T *operator->() { return &curr->data; }
    };

    Iterator begin()
    {
        Iterator it(this);
        return it;
    }

    Iterator end()
    {
        Iterator it(this);
        if (it == nullptr)
        {
            return it;
        }

        while (it.curr != nullptr)
        {
            it++;
        }
        return it;
    }
```

This is how I am trying to use it in main.cpp

```
    Matrix<int> mat1(3, 3);
    mat1.fillMatrix();

    auto it = Matrix<int>::Iterator(mat1.begin());

    while (it != mat1.end())
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        it++;
    }
```

Comment: Do you believe `it.curr` will suddenly become the null pointer if you increment it far enough? (And if it did, why would incrementing it until that point be different from just setting it to the null pointer directly?)

Comment: No, I don't think it will become nullptr

Comment: Then what is the purpose (in `end`) of incrementing it until it *is* null?

Comment: And what should the end() method look like then? It must also point after the last element

Comment: But if I do this, I have to change the whole Iterator class, how then to call it from the main? Pass matrix size to iterator constructor?

Comment: Changing a whole class is normal. Don't fall in love with what you've already written.

Comment: And you don't need to change the whole class - just one constructor of the iterator, and then `begin()` to `return Iterator(data);`, and `end()` to `return Iterator(data + rows * cols * sizeof(T);`. (And you need to fix your `operator*` and `operator->`, not because of this change but because they are already broken.)

Comment: Also, `auto it = mat1.begin();` is enough.

Comment: Anyway, when I try to do cout << *it << endl, I get an error: request for member 'data' in '*((myMatrix::Matrix<int>::Iterator*)this)->myMatrix::Matrix< int>::Iterator::curr', which is of non-class type 'int'
   133 | T &operator*() { return curr->data; }. Although I did not change this method and it worked ...

Comment: Also a Matrix is a 2 dimensional thing. How will you know when to add a linebreak in the output? You should have a `RowIterator` that in turn has a `ColumnIterator`. Really just first implement a `Vector<T>` and then define the Matrix as `class Matrix : public Vector<Vector<T>>` and add the functions that are specific to a Matrix, like multiplication with a `Vector<T>`.

Comment: @ЕлизаветаТараненко Can you think of how to calculate the address of the end of the array?

Comment: Yes, for example data + (row*cols)

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, by assignment it is forbidden to use STL containers. And to be honest, I have a division into rows and columns, but it happened by accident, I don’t even know how it happened that it works. If you need - I can show the whole code, for example in pastebin

Comment: That doesn't stop you from implementing a Vector class.